# Getting exit status of child process without wait()?

Tags: c, unix, signals, child-process, terminate

Is there a way to get the exit status of a child process created by `fork()` system call without the parent process pausing/waiting for its execution?

Specifically I need to print out the status of the exited process after it's done, but with the parent process continuing to do its thing in the meantime.

Still a beginner here; so as far as I know, you can't do that without using `wait()` and then testing it with the macros.

Comment: See duplicate: what you want is to use the parameter `WNOHANG` with `waitpid` function.

Comment: `SIGCHLD` might help you. But you still need some `wait` for getting the exit status.